# KEDA scaledown event take 5 minute

Tags: kubernetes, horizontal-pod-autoscaling, keda

My pods used to scale down in few seconds 20-30 but i dont know what happened now it taken 5 minute to scale down and when I added minreplica in KEDA YML  file the time from 1 to 0 pods take few seconds but for n to 1 pod it take 5 minutes what I understanded that thus HPA behaviour it take the responsability of scale down from n ->1 pod and from 1->0 pod KEDA is responsible for the event
I added this to scaledobject file but its being ignored

```
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    name: consumer-deployment
  pollingInterval: 5
  cooldownPeriod: 10
  minReplicaCount: 0
  maxReplicaCount: 5
```

how to reduce this time that is by default 5 minute

**Im using k8s with docker desktop **

Comment: I carefully read your response, but unfortunately, the problem hasn't been resolved yet. As you mentioned,  the role of coolInterval and pollingInterval , which have default values of 300 seconds. However, in my configuration, I have set them to a lower value, I think they being ignored or something like this.

it weird  that this problem appeared out of nowhere. I haven't made any changes to the KEDA YAML file since I created it, and it was functioning perfectly .

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [document](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/concepts/scaling-deployments/) :

> The period to wait after the last trigger reported active before
> scaling the resource back to 0. By default it’s 5 minutes (300
> seconds).
>
> The cooldownPeriod only applies after a trigger occurs; when you first
> create your Deployment (or StatefulSet/CustomResource), KEDA will
> immediately scale it to minReplicaCount. Additionally, the KEDA
> cooldownPeriod only applies when scaling to 0; scaling from 1 to N
> replicas is handled by the Kubernetes HPA.

Your cool down period will be dependent on pollingInterval. This is the interval to check each trigger on. By default KEDA will check each trigger source on every ScaledObject every 30 seconds. So you can minimize pollingInternal time to reduce your cool down period.

However,you can enable/disable scaling rules either by editing the replica count to 0 or you can use a single field called [Pause autoscaling](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/concepts/scaling-deployments/#pause-autoscaling).

Add this below annotation to your deployment :

```
metadata:
   annotations:
      autoscaling.keda.sh/paused-replicas: "0"
```

> This annotation will pause autoscaling no matter what number of
> replicas is provided. The above annotation will scale your current
> workload to 0 replicas and pause autoscaling. You can set the value of
> replicas for an object to be paused at any arbitrary number. To enable
> autoscaling again, simply remove the annotation from the ScaledObject
> definition.

Comment: excuse my question I just started learnig k8 :
the pause replica config will pause HPA from autoscaling and KEDA will stay function normaly or the hole autoscaling process will stop ?

Comment: Pause autoscaling can be useful to instruct KEDA to pause autoscaling of objects, if you want to do to cluster maintenance or you want to avoid resource starvation by removing non-mission-critical workloads. Hence it will pause the whole autoscaling process. Refer to this [link](https://keda.sh/docs/2.10/concepts/scaling-deployments/#pause-autoscaling) for more information.